# Make PDF help files open automatically

Tags: html, r

In R, if we set the `help_type` argument of `help()` function to `html` and call it, it will automatically open the html help in a browser. However, this is not the case for `help_type = 'pdf'`. Only the pdf is generated. How can I make it automatically after the help file is generated? I believe that pdf help are preferred by some as it can display mathematical formula properly, the html help dont.

Comment: What OS are you using? You can try with `system(paste(<path to pdf reader>, <path to help file>))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on aL3xa comment, under Windows you could use `shell.exec` to view pdf.

```
help("plot", help_type="pdf") # help file is saved in working directory
shell.exec(file.path(getwd(), "plot.pdf"))
```

Comment: I have modified your code to create a function to automate the opening of the pdf help file. I wonder why R does not do that by default.

Comment: Help system in R is changing all the time, I don't be surprised if that option will be available in one of next versions.